# How to convert an object containing DateTime fields to JSON in Dart?

Tags: json, dart

I try to convert an object to JSON.

```dart
  var obj = { "dt": new DateTime.now() };
  var s = stringify(obj);
```

The runtime throws an exception: "Calling toJson method on object failed."

That's expected since DateTime class doesn't have *toJson* method.
But what should I do in this case?

Javascript's `JSON.stringify` function has an optional argument *replacer* which allows me to provide my own way of serialization of any object even if the object has no toJson method. Is there any similar facility in Dart or maybe I can extend somehow DateTime class with my own toJson method?

Answer (score 19):

JSON conversion only works with maps, lists, strings, numbers, booleans, or null. So what if your object contains another type like `DateTime`?

## DateTime → JSON

Let's start with the following object:

```
class Person {
  Person(this.name, this.birthdate);
  String name;
  DateTime birthdate;
}
```

You can convert it to a map like this:

```
final person = Person('Bob', DateTime(2020, 2, 25));

Map<String, dynamic> map = {
 'name': person.name,
 'birthdate': person.birthdate,
};
```

If you tried to encode this right now with `jsonEncode` (or `json.encode`), you would get an error because the `DateTime` is not directly serializeable. There are two solutions.

#### Solution 1

You could serialize it yourself first like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  'name': person.name,
  'birthdate': person.birthdate.toIso8601String(),
};

final jsonString = json.encode(map);
```

**Note:**

Here is the difference between `toString` and `toIso8601String`:

```
2020-02-25 14:44:28.534 // toString()
2020-02-25T14:44:28.534 // toIso8601String()
```

The `toIso8601String` doesn't have any spaces so that makes it nicer for conversions and sending over APIs that might not deal with spaces well.

#### Solution 2

You could use the optional `toEncodable` function parameter on `jsonEncode`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final person = Person('Bob', DateTime(2020, 2, 25));

  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'name': person.name,
    'birthdate': person.birthdate,
  };

  final toJson = json.encode(map, toEncodable: myDateSerializer);
}

dynamic myDateSerializer(dynamic object) {
  if (object is DateTime) {
    return object.toIso8601String();
  }
  return object;
}
```

The `toEncodable` function just converts the input to a string or something that `jsonEncode` can covert to a string.

## JSON → DateTime

There is nothing special here. You just have to parse the string into the type that you need. In the case of `DateTime` you can use its `parse` or `tryParse` methods.

```
final myMap= json.decode(jsonString);
final name = myMap['name'];
final birthdateString = myMap['birthdate'];
final birthdate = DateTime.parse(birthdateString);
final decodedPerson = Person(name, birthdate);
```

Note that `parse` will throw an exception if the format of the string cannot be parsed into a `DateTime` object.

## As a model class

```
class Person {

  Person(this.name, this.birthdate);

  String name;
  DateTime birthdate;

  Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        birthdate = DateTime.tryParse(json['birthdate']),

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'birthdate': birthdate.toIso8601String(),
    };
  }
}
```

This will not throw an exception is the date is malformatted, but `birthdate` would be `null`.

## Notes

- See my fuller answer [here](https://medium.com/@suragch/parsing-simple-json-in-flutter-83ee1809a6ab).
- Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564660/3681880) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Zdeslav Vojkovic's answer is outdated now.

The `JSON.encode()` method in `dart:convert` has an optional `toEncodable` method that is invoked for objects that are not natively serializable to JSON. It's then up to the user to provide a closure that returns an appropriate serialization of the DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, it's a flaw in `dart:json` library that `stringify` doesn't support additional callback to serialize types lacking the implementation of `toJson`. Strangely enough, `parse` function does support `reviver` argument to customize the deserialization process. Probably the reason was along the lines that user can add `toJson` for their on types, and core library will take care of 'native' types, but `DateTime` was omitted (maybe because date serialization in JSON is not really a straightforward story).

Maybe the goal of the team was to use custom types instead of Maps (which is nice), but the drawback here is that if your custom type contains 10 other properties and 1 which is of `DateTime` type, you need to implement `toJson` which serializes all of them, even integers and strings. Hopefully, once when Mirror API is ready, there will be libraries that implement serialization 'out-of-band' by reading the reflected info on type, see lower for an example. The promise of Dart is that I would be able to use my types both on server and client, but if I have to manually implement serialization/deserialization for all my models then it is too awkward to be usable.

it also doesn't help that `DateTime` itself is not very flexible with formatting, as there are no other methods besides `toString` which returns the format useless for serialization.

So here are some options:

- wrap (or derive from) `DateTime` in your own type which provides `toJson`
- patch `json.stringifyJsonValue` and submit the change or at least submit an issue :)
- use some 3-rd party library like [`json-object`](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_object) (just an example, it also doesn't support `DateTime` serialization, AFAIK

I am not really happy with any of them :)

Comment: Date formatting is here http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/intl/DateFormat.html There is a bug for adding a replacer function argument to stringify() https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5911

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about it (I checked the core lib, but 'intl' has to be installed separately). I guess that ISO8601/RFC3339 formats still have to be built 'manually', right? also since they are not really 'localized' I am not sure if they would really fit to `intl`. A good serialization lib is needed, but I guess it makes no sense before mirror API is done.

Comment: The DateTime object has fields that can be used to extract its data without trying to parse a string. Or it would be easy to generate a hard-coded format new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") to print ISO form. It's not localized, but it prints what you want. There is also a serialization library, which can use mirrors if available, but which also lets you write hard-coded rules. It's more aimed at being able to read back the data into dart than producing JSON for consumption by another program.

Comment: sure, I am aware of that - that's what I mention as 'built manually', but I find it a bit awkward. there are no extension methods, so you can't attach it to `DateFormat`. thus it needs to be a separate function in my code (or a hard-coded instance), which means that data formatting is split among DateTime, DateFormat and my function/instance.

Comment: @Zdeslav Packages such as intl are imported using pub instead of core as this means the VM image can be smaller, allowing it to start up quicker. Here's a link to the serialization lib that Alan mentioned http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/serialization.html Also have a look at SimpleJsonFormat.

Comment: I know, I don't have objections to that - I have just missed it. serialization lib wouldn't help here if I am correct, as it returns a `Map` and then you have the same problem if it contains a `DateTime` field. Since `DateTime` is frequently used, I believe that 'json.stringify' should be extended to support it (e.g in RFC3339 UTC format)

Answer (score 0):

I've added a new package to Dart [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) that allows json serialization of objects within a structure. This package [Jsonize](https://pub.dev/packages/jsonize%5D) serialize and deserialize custom classes, and handles DateTime out of the box:

```
  List<dynamic> myList = [1, "Hello!", DateTime.now()];
  var jsonRep = Jsonize.toJson(myList);
  var myDeserializedList = Jsonize.fromJson(jsonRep);
```

So will do with your example

```
  var obj = { "dt": new DateTime.now() };
  var s = Jsonize.toJson(obj);
  var obj2 = Jsonize.fromJson(s);
```

but can do also this

```
  var obj = DateTime.now();
  var s = Jsonize.toJson(obj);
  var dt = Jsonize.fromJson(s);
```