# How to convert DateTime object to json

Tags: json, dart

How to convert `DateTime` object to json? It throws `Converting object to an encodable object failed.`, so is this a bug or it's just `dart` haven't yet support it? If you guys know some workaround please let me know.

Answer (score 50):

Rather than using a wrapper, you can also create your own custom encoder passing the [toEncodable](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_convert/JsonCodec@id_encode) argument.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;

void main() {
  var dt = new DateTime.now();
  var str = JSON.encode(dt, toEncodable: myEncode);
  print(str);
}

dynamic myEncode(dynamic item) {
  if(item is DateTime) {
    return item.toIso8601String();
  }
  return item;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

you are encoding object(DateTime) into other encodable object **JSON.encode(DateTime.Now())** which is not possible in dart programming.

> So, convert it to dart supported Date to String conversion that is :
>   add : **.toIso8601String()** at the end

**JSON.encode(DateTime.Now().toIso8601String()),this resolves your error.**
// i am taking DateTime.Now() just for example.

Answer (score 2):

first: JSON does not support date/time encoding.. this is usually done by convention depending on the other party - usually a string representation (e.g. ISO8601 but Microsoft's ASP.NET uses a custom format).

second: [How to convert an object containing DateTime fields to JSON in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537114/how-to-convert-an-object-containing-datetime-fields-to-json-in-dart)

(In short: Runtime does not serialise DateTime. You'll need to create a wrapper with custom serialisation logic.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just convert your map in Dart.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> encodeMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is DateTime) {
      map[key] = value.toString();
    }
  });
  return map;
}
```

Usage: `var _map = encodeMap(_data);`