# How can I format a DateTime instance to Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to send an DateTime instance per Json. I know how to decode DateTime from a Json file. But how can I encode it correctly?

DateTime birthdate;
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
'birthDate': birthdate,
};

Does not work

Comment: It depends on how you want a date/time to be represented in your JSON structure.  There are many possible ways.

Comment: Can you show me a regular used one? I think it will work

Comment: There is no "regular one".  You can choose to store a date/time as an integer representing the number of seconds from the Unix epoch, an integer for the number of milliseconds, a `YYYY-MM-DD` string, a `DD-MM-YYYY` string, a `MM-DD-YYYY` string, ...

Comment: This is solve https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389537/12212907

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
      DateTime myBirthday = DateTime.now();
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject = {
         'birthday': myBirthday,
      };
      return jsonObject;
   }
```